# Express, error - connectRedis is not a function - Solved the problem by installing connect-redis version 6 instead of 7

Tags: node.js, redis, connect-redis

```
Ubuntu Mate 22.04.2 lts
Node 18.16.0
Redis 7.0.11 - without password (no auth), ping-pong test passes
"body-parser": "^1.20.2"
"connect-redis": "^7.1.0"
"cors": "^2.8.5"
"dotenv": "^16.3.1"
"express": "^4.18.2"
"express-session": "^1.17.3"
"redis": "^4.6.7"
```

I am trying to run the example - https://devdotcode.com/how-to-manage-session-in-nodejs-using-redis-store/
And i get the error:

```
const redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
                                           ^
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dol/MyPrograms/redis03/index.js:19:44)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Second example - https://medium.com/swlh/session-management-in-nodejs-using-redis-as-session-store-64186112aa9
Error:

```
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session)
                   ^
TypeError: connectRedis is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dol/MyPrograms/redis01/index.js:11:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to understand the documentation - https://developer.redis.com
But there are too complicated examples

Answer (score 3):

I see you solved this issue by using version 6 of connect-redis, in the case of version 7, try this:

```
const session = require("express-session");
const redis = require("redis");
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default;
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    url: "redis://redis:6379",
});

redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);



let redisStore = new RedisStore({
    client: redisClient,
});

app.use(
   session({
     store: redisStore,
     secret: "SESSION_SECRET",
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: false,
     cookie: {
       secure: false,
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are opening (starting) redisClient port. add separate call for connect and quit, like this -

```
await redis.connect();
const result = await redis.get(key);
await redis.quit();
```

Comment: the port is 6379

Comment: Please explain in detail.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Error message is correct. In your example redisStore is not a function, it's a class - based on a current documentation on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis

Try this:

```
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis');
const session = require('express-session');
const { createClient } = require('redis');

const redisClient = createClient();
redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);

const redisStore = new RedisStore({
  client: redisClient,
  prefix: "prefix:",
});

app.use(
  session({
    store: redisStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false, 
    secret: "keyboard cat",
  })
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this example doesn't work

Comment: const redisStore = new RedisStore({
                   ^

TypeError: RedisStore is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dol/MyPrograms/redis02/index.js:8:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Comment: please try  importing RedisStore this way:
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default;

Comment: This didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Like **ethArek** said above, after looking at the documentation the error should be expected, at first i forgot to install redis locally, the code provided by him (the correct way to connect to redis) worked just fine.

**Make sure that Redis is listening on the correct address and port**

```
const redisClient = createClient({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
});
```

Comment: Settings are correct, because no problem with redis-connect v6

Answer (score 0):

Follow the "Migration from v6" chapter of [Release notes](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/releases)

Uninstalling of `@types/connect-redis` was helpfull for me.